# Parsing URL jQuery AJAX form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, url

Basically i'm trying to send a video along with other info through jQuery to PHP to be written to a txt file to be read later.

There is a way of inputting a video url into this. I've got everything working except one thing.

If i put this through: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1lBwbhlPtM
it works fine.

but this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1lBwbhlPtM&feature=feedu
doesn't.

I've done some tests and it's because when i send the second url through &feature=feedu gets read as a separate $_POST value.

This is the problem:

```
    var dataString = 'title='+title+'&content='+content+'&date='+date+'&Submit=YES';
```

because its reading like

`var dataString = 'title='+title+'&content='+IMAGES, TEXT AND STUFF+'&feature=feedu OTHER IMAGES AND STUFF&date='+date+'&Submit=YES';`

it's out of a textarea that could include images or text and stuff so im looking for something like htmlspecialchars() to sort out that & before sending it through ajax

Any ideas how to solve this?

EDIT:
Here's the full code that's the problem:

```
    var title = $('input#title').val(); 
    var content = $('textarea#content').val();
    var date = $('input#date').val();
    var dataString = 'title='+title+'&content='+content+'&date='+date+'&Submit=YES'; 
    //alert (dataString);return false;
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "./inc/php/file.php",
     dataType: "json",
     data: dataString,
     success: function(data) {
        if(data.error == true){
             $('.errordiv').show().html(data.message);
        }else{
             $('.errordiv').show().html(data.message);
             $(':input','#addstuff')
                .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
                .val('')
                .removeAttr('checked')
                .removeAttr('selected');
        }
       },
       error: function(data) {
        $('.errordiv').html(data.message+' --- SCRIPT ERROR');
       }

    })
    return false;
```

if content equals:

```
&content= <br>Text 1<br> <img>http://someimage.com/image.jpg</img> 
<br> Text2<br> <vid>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=isDIHIHI&feature=feedu</vid> 
<br>Text 3<br>
```

the content variable gets put through the ajax call as:

```
&content= <br>Text 1<br> <img>http://someimage.com/image.jpg</img> 
<br> Text2<br> <vid>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=isDIHIHI
```

with an extra variable that is

```
&feature=feedu</vid> 
<br>Text 3<br>
```

So how do u stop the ajax reading &feature as a separate $_POST variable?

Answer (score 0):

Did you `encodeURI()` before pass the your video url?

If you need it in PHP then [URLEncode](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: it's out of a textarea that could include images or text and stuff so im looking for something like htmlspecialchars() to sort out that & before sending it through ajax

Comment: nah it's sorting the & sign out before putting it through the ajax.
At the moment if i add $_POST['feature'] to the end of my content before writing it to the file i get feedu

Comment: Maybe show us how do you pass it into ajax and I can help better

Answer (score 0):

I used this bit of code in the php file

```
if(isset($_POST['feature'])){
    $content=htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes(nl2br("<br />".$_POST['content'].'&feature='.$_POST['feature']."<br />")));
}
```

But it's not very dynamic as it only applies to youtube URLs

Answer (score 0):

In JS do (before ajaxing)

```
dataString = encodeURI(dataString);
```

And then decode it on PHP

```
$dataString = urldecode($_POST['data']);
```

Or do:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "./inc/php/file.php",
     dataType: "json",
     data: {
       'title': $('input#title').val(),
       'content': $('textarea#content').val(),
       'date': $('input#date').val(),
       'Submit': 'Yes'
     }
     success: function(data) {
        if(data.error == true){
             $('.errordiv').show().html(data.message);
        }else{
             $('.errordiv').show().html(data.message);
             $(':input','#addstuff')
                .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
                .val('')
                .removeAttr('checked')
                .removeAttr('selected');
        }
       },
       error: function(data) {
        $('.errordiv').html(data.message+' --- SCRIPT ERROR');
       }

    })
```